# Humble design suggestion for Stack Snippets: de-emphasize "Copy to answer" button

Tags: discussion, design, stack-snippets

I am absolutely, no doubt about it, not a designer.

That said, what do you think about:

[image: Primary and secondary buttons]

In my mind drawing the "Copy snippet to answer" link less primary is prettier:

- It draws attention to the main button.  While it's way useful, I've only clicked that a few times and almost always only on questions.
- Cuts down on the visual hugeness.  In my humble opinion, having those two big bold blue buttons are a bit crazy.  With your great page designs, they are absolutely the biggest, most "click me!!!" buttons in any given stack exchange page.

Anyway, I won't even pretend to be any kind of designer, but does this seem like a good idea?

Comment: Please add the image of existing design for comparison.